# ASP File Permissions

Tags: asp-classic, permissions

I'm a ASP.NET developer who was contacted by a client asking me to make some changes to their site after someone told them it was ASP.NET. It wasn't, it was classic ASP but she seemed at her wits end with it so I said I would give it a go. However I have very little experience with Classic ASP.

Am currently trying to update a form. Have copied the entire site and database to my local machine and got it up and running. I have set the Anonymous user to my windows user to allow me to connect to the database using windows authentication.

The difficulty I am having is when I go to edit an existing record using the edit form and click save on my local machine I get the following error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/xtpropertyedit.asp, line 200

800401f3
```

However it works fine on the hosted version of the site. I imagine this is an permissions issue. I have tried adding my user with full permissions to the root folder of the site on my local machine but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
Set Jpeg = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Jpeg")    '** Line 200 **
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What type of object is it trying to create?  Can we see the code around line 200 of xtpropertyedit.asp?

Comment: it's possible/likely that the object it's trying to create is either not present or not registered on your machine.  Like @ste suggested, show us the line that's causing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AspJpeg](http://www.aspjpeg.com/) is a paid third-party component and seems like it's not installed on your development computer. It can be used without any limitation for 30 days.

Comment: Eurgh! Bloody 3rd party components. Thanks for tip, will just comment that section out for now until I need upload it back to the server.